# main.cpp:10:24: error: cannot convert ‘’ to ‘std::string** {aka std::basic_string**}’ in assignment

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Deka{
    string **Koloda;
};

void SozKol(Deka *objkoloda){

    objkoloda -> Koloda={
        {"6b", "7b", "8b", "9b", "10b", "Jb", "Qb", "Kb", "Ab"},
        {"6k", "7k", "8k", "9k", "10k", "Jk", "Qk", "Kk", "Ak"},
        {"6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "10h", "Jh", "Qh", "Kh", "Ah"},
        {"6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "Jp", "Qp", "Kp", "Ap"}
    };
}

int main() {
    Deka objkoloda;
    SozKol(&objkoloda);
    cout << objkoloda.Koloda[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Откровенно говоря, вообще смущает решения тягать в каждом объекте все названия... Работать-то проще с числами, а названия пусть бы себе где-то лежали - одни на программу (да и генерировать их из чисел очень просто, так что их в явном виде можно и не хранить).

Answer (score 2):

Указатели - это не массивы. Нельзя просто положить набор элементов "в указатель" - сначала вам нужно выделить память через `new`.

Чтобы не мучаться, просто возьмите `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Deka
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> Koloda;
};

void SozKol(Deka *objkoloda)
{
    objkoloda->Koloda = {
        {"6b", "7b", "8b", "9b", "10b", "Jb", "Qb", "Kb", "Ab"},
        {"6k", "7k", "8k", "9k", "10k", "Jk", "Qk", "Kk", "Ak"},
        {"6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "10h", "Jh", "Qh", "Kh", "Ah"},
        {"6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "Jp", "Qp", "Kp", "Ap"},
    };
}

int main()
{
    Deka objkoloda;
    SozKol(&objkoloda);
    std::cout << objkoloda.Koloda[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

---

Еще: Вместо того, чтобы вручную записывать кучу названий карт, их можно сгенерировать парой циклов `for`:

```
void SozKol(Deka *objkoloda)
{
    objkoloda->Koloda = {};

    for (char b : std::string("bkhp"))        
    {
        auto &v = objkoloda->Koloda.emplace_back();
        for (const std::string &a : {"6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"})
            v.push_back(a + b);
    }
}
```